# Get measurement IDs of all GTM-loaded config tags

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am loading a GTM container on the page using the GTM snippet. I need to obtain all measurement IDs that are loaded via GTM but cannot seem to find a way. I’ve looked at the “google_tag_data and google_tag_manager objects to no avail. I’ve googled myself blue. This is an enterprise-level integration where the implementing page can choose to use GTM and/or send individual tracking IDs (where I use gtag). The purpose for obtaining the IDs is because I need to send custom events using the dataLayer but it doesn’t work unless I provide the “send_to” parameter with all IDs. Leaving this blank only sends events to the initial property.

Some code for clarification:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
            'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
        }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<script>
    window.gtag = window.gtag || function () { window.dataLayer.push(arguments); }
</script>
```

The above loads GTM. Within this GTM container, there are one or more GA4 Configuration Tags firing. Later in the page, the following code needs access to these IDs:

```
var streamIds = ???;

window.gtag('event', 'something_happened', {
    'event_category': 'category',
    'event_label': 'label',
    'value': 'value',
    'event_callback': callback,
    'send_to': streamIds
});
```

I cannot find any Tag fired callback or events documented, nor any access to these IDs in the "google_tag_data" or "google_tag_manager" global objects, nor does the dataLayer contain anything useful.

The caveat to this is that I cannot access the GTM container or tag configurations. I just need to know what's being fired on the page. I am assuming this is hidden information Google does not want to expose via any interface but hoping for a workaround that's mostly future-proof.

UPDATE:

I have found that "window.google_tag_manager.mb.h" stores messages from GTM which contain "config" messages and I can retrieve the IDs from here. However, the properties are dynamically compiled to "mb" and "h" leading me to believe these may change if the library is updated.

Comment: You should improve your question. Please take your time and describe the problem in a calm manner.

Comment: @BNazaruk - Question updated. Hope that helps.

Comment: This might not be the most streamlined way of doing it...but you could open devTools and go to the Source menu. If you are using GA4, there will be the ID under www.googletagmanager.com >> gtag folders.

Comment: @A_Patterson - Appreciate the response; however, I need to obtain the IDs via JavaScript.

Comment: Understood. When you looked at the google_tag_manager global objects, were there not GA4 IDs listed? In the console, I was able to locate two arrays that were the IDs the specific properties.

Comment: @A_Patterson yes, as I mentioned in the question update, am able to see these IDs but they are located within an array that has a dynamic property name (e.g. “mb.h”) which will likely  change the next time the JS is updated/minified. There’s does not appear to be a supported, future-proof means to fetch these values.

Comment: You should rewrite the first paragraph properly. It's sloppy. I can't understand your situation precisely. It seems to me you have a few much better solutions than trying to get measurement ids from GTM. The whole idea of getting measurement ids from GTM sounds like a bad tracking architecture. This is something you're not supposed to want to do.